# Is it possible to give `git bisect` a set of invalid commits to always skip?

Tags: git, git-bisect

On long project, there can be a whole bunch of commits it's not worth trying during bisection e.g.

- commits which are known to be broken
- commits which are otherwise part of a PR not guaranteeing validity

The second one can mostly be handled by using `bisect --first-parent` though it requires remembering to use it, but the first one is more of an issue.

A script for `bisect run` can provide the feature, but then that needs to be a meta-script which either runs a sub-script (for the `bisect run` case) or acts as a shell taking `old`/`new`/`skip` commands to pass them along when a commit should be included.

Comment: `man git bisect` says for `Bisect run`: *The special exit code 125 should be used when the current source code cannot be tested.* can you not use this in your script after determining that the current commit is invalid?

Comment: From what I understand OP is aware of scripts being able to skip, but wants to *always* skip certain commits that are broken, whenever OP is bisecting. Without having to write a skip-script that he always has to remember to chain/wrap the actual bisect-run-script with. (Or a shell if interactive). The question basically is: "Is there a way to permanently blacklist certain commits in git bisect, so that they don't need to be skipped (by hand or script) when bisecting"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file, somewhere, e.g. bisect.blacklist with a list of the bad commits like this:

```
git bisect skip bef63087981a1033239f664e6772f86080bdec44
git bisect skip 72d1195b9b3919d1468d688909985b8f398c7e70
git bisect skip aef63087981a1033239f664e6772186080bdec3e
```

Then whenever you start bisecting with `git bisect start`, also run

```
git bisect replay bisect.blacklist
```

After that you should be able to bisect normally (be it by hand or by script), with git bisect already knowing to skip those commits.

If those commits are generally broken when it comes to bisecting, you could also track that file in git for extra convenience.

Hint: If you add `git bisect start` at the start of the blacklist file, then you don't have to run it manually before the `replay` command.

Comment: Smart. Much better than my suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Have your bisect run script check for your known invalid revisions and [exit with 125](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_bisect_run):

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -qxF "$(git rev-parse HEAD)" /path/to/invalid-revisions.txt && exit 125

# your real script here, or source/call your real script
```

`/path/to/invalid-revisions.txt` would contain one full commit hash per line. `grep -qxF` matches only full lines with the exact fixed string as provided, but in quiet mode. `git rev-parse HEAD` gives you the full commit hash of the commit currently being tested by bisect.

The logic to detect invalid commits can be as simple or as complicated as you need. You can check the content of the working tree, the build status, the commit message, the author, anything really.